# Reading and writing unicode characters to file in C

Tags: c, unicode

I am trying to create a program that saves unicode characters in a text file (named data.txt below) and when I load the file again they will be correctly printed in the terminal. This is my code:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)
#define ON_WINDOWS
#endif

#ifdef ON_WINDOWS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <io.h>     // _setmode
#include <fcntl.h>  // _O_U16TEXT

// just in case mingw doesn't define it after all:
#ifndef _O_U16TEXT
#define _O_U16TEXT (0x20000)
#endif
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#define SIZE 100

void set_locale_mode() {
#ifdef ON_WINDOWS
   // Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order (BMP of ISO 10646)
   const char* CP_UTF_16LE = ".1200";

   setlocale(LC_ALL, CP_UTF_16LE);
   _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
   _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
#else
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
#endif
}

int main(void) {

   set_locale_mode();

   wchar_t myString[SIZE];
   wchar_t loadedString[SIZE];

   wprintf(L"Enter 3 characters: ");
   wscanf(L"%ls", myString);
   wprintf(L"Your input is %ls\n", myString);

   FILE *pFile;

   if(pFile=fopen("data.txt", "w")) {
      fwprintf(pFile, L"%ls", myString);
   } else {
      wprintf(L"Failed to write to file!\n");
   }

   fclose(pFile);

   if(pFile=fopen("data.txt", "r")) {
      fwscanf(pFile, L"%ls", loadedString);
   } else {
    wprintf(L"Failed to read from file!\n");
   } 

   fclose(pFile);

   wprintf(L"Loaded string is %ls", loadedString);

   return 0;
}
```

The following 2 examples work as intended:

First one:

```
Enter 3 characters: abc
Your input is abc
Loaded string is abc
```

Second one:

```
Enter 3 characters: åäö
Your input is åäö
Loaded string is åäö
```

However, in the third attempt, I copied some chinese characters and copied them into the terminal and this was the outcome:

```
Enter 3 characters: 买买买
Your input is 买买买
Loaded string is 炨}ﺨa眬☺
```

The loaded string is obviously not what I intended. Why does it not work and how do I fix it?

Edit: I am on Windows and uses MINGW32 and uses VSCode.

Comment: Very nice title!  :)

Comment: I knew it would happen some day xD

Comment: on one of linuxes that code works as it supposed `Enter 3 characters: 买买买
Your input is 买买买
Loaded string is 买买买
`

Comment: The locale and file mode handling for Windows looks deeply problematic.  The locale handling for non-Windows looks pointless.

Comment: I understand why you turned to the wide-oriented I/O functions, but they are probably a red herring.

Comment: If you have not already done so, then now is the time to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Comment: @JohnBollinger is windows mentioned somewhere in the q?

Comment: @yvs2014, the code uses Windows-specific preprocessor symbols to detect whether it is being built on Windows, and defines a macro `ON_WINDOWS` if it does detect that.  It uses that for conditional compilation.  So yes, Windows is fairly prominent in the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger "if it does detect that": if doesn't, then doesn't. Okay, sorry haven't got that windows is only option unless otherwise stated

Comment: On which platform did you run your program to get the specified output? Was it Windows? Or was it some other platform?

Comment: Who said anything about a default or only option, @yvs2014?  The Windows support is elaborately enough developed that I suspect it to be the OP's primary target, but my previous comment about how it handles that applies no matter what the primary development environment may be.

Comment: Yeap, "The locale handling for non-Windows looks pointless." @JohnBollinger

Comment: btw, it works on Windows11 (at least in cygwin terminal): `Enter 3 characters:  女人买车，男人买卡车
Your input is 女人买车，男人买卡车
Loaded string is 女人买车，男人买卡车`
and
`win11:pty0 % uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0-22621 win11 3.4.6-1.x86_64 2023-02-14 13:23 UTC x86_64 Cygwin`

Comment: Look at the file you've created. Does it contain what you have supposedly written to it?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit `win11:pty0 % cat data.txt` displays `女人买车，男人买卡车%`

Comment: @yvs2014 It's great that it's working for you, I was asking OP.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit it's still not even clear what OP's target system is

Comment: @yvs2014 Obviously the one that doesn't work with unicode out of the box in 2023. I wonder what it could be.

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson "Why does it not work and how do I fix it?" --> The first step should have been to add test to the return values of the various functions to see if they report an error.

Comment: I added some info in my edit

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since you open two new streams, you need to set them in the proper mode too:

```c
if (pFile = fopen("data.txt", "w")) {
#ifdef ON_WINDOWS
    _setmode(_fileno(pFile), _O_U16TEXT);      // <- here
#endif
    fwprintf(pFile, L"%ls", myString);
} else {
    wprintf(L"Failed to write to file!\n");
}

fclose(pFile);

if (pFile = fopen("data.txt", "r")) {
#ifdef ON_WINDOWS
    _setmode(_fileno(pFile), _O_U16TEXT);      // <- here
#endif
    fwscanf(pFile, L"%99ls", loadedString);
} else {
    wprintf(L"Failed to read from file!\n");
}
```

Also note the `99` in the `L"%99ls"`. If you use the `scanf` family of functions to read words from streams, *always* set the max number of characters to read at most one less than the size of the buffer.

---

On Windows, you can also open the files with the correct mode, `UTF-16LE`, directly:

```c
#ifdef ON_WINDOWS
if (pFile = fopen("data.txt", "w, ccs=UTF-16LE")) { // <- here
#else
if (pFile = fopen("data.txt", "w")) {
#endif
    fwprintf(pFile, L"%ls", myString);
} else {
    wprintf(L"Failed to write to file!\n");
}

fclose(pFile);

#ifdef ON_WINDOWS
if (pFile = fopen("data.txt", "r, ccs=UTF-16LE")) { // <- here
#else
if (pFile = fopen("data.txt", "r")) {
#endif
    fwscanf(pFile, L"%99ls", loadedString);
} else {
    wprintf(L"Failed to read from file!\n");
}
```

Comment: This works, but why did my version work with åäö and not 买买买?

Comment: @AlexanderJonsson `åäö` was saved as `0xE5 0x00 0xE4 0x00 0xF6 0x00` (if inspected in binary mode) and I assume those maps to `åäö`  in the active codepage. `买买买` was saved as `0x70 0x4E 0x70 0x4E 0x70 0x4E` and I assume that doesn't map back to the original in the current codepage. Using `_setmode` to set the stream into UTF-16LE translation mode fixes that issue. But I'm not very good at these things. Perhaps [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76584248/7582247) provides better details about how it works "under the hood".

Answer (score 1):

For the program's purposes, there are three important locuses for character handling:

- the terminal
- the program
- the file

Each one will have a character encoding by which it represents characters as numbers, and a set of characters that they recognize.  These are not necessarily the same for the various locuses, but it's convenient if they are.

If the point is to capture character data from the terminal and ultimately to echo it back to the terminal, then it's important to understand that how the program must handle that is sensitive to the encoding the terminal is using, and that *that is outside the program's control*.  In particular, the program setting its locale does not influence the form in which the terminal will deliver character data to it, but it does influence how your program *interprets* the data from the terminal.  If the terminal and your program disagree about that then data corruption is a likely result.

On the other hand, your particular program doesn't need to be concerned with what specific encoding the terminal is using -- it just needs to store the data it receives and then echo it back accurately.

If the terminal is not operating in a wide-character mode, then trying to read from it or write to it with wide-oriented I/O functions is likely to mess you up.  And wide-character terminal modes are unusual these days, because UTF-8-based modes, which are byte-oriented, are pretty much universally available, and are more convenient to work with for most purposes.  If you can rely on the terminal running in a byte-oriented mode (it doesn't matter which in particular) then you're going way out of your way.  In that case, you probably don't need to do anything special -- Unicode characters your terminal handles at all should just work:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(__MINGW64__)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {
   char myString[SIZE];
   char loadedString[SIZE];

   printf("Enter 3 characters: ");
   scanf("%99s", myString);
   printf("Your input is %s\n", myString);

   FILE *pFile;

   if (pFile = fopen("data.txt", "w")) {
      fprintf(pFile, "%s", myString);
   } else {
      printf("Failed to open file for writing!\n");
   }
   fclose(pFile);

   if (pFile = fopen("data.txt", "r")) {
      fscanf(pFile, "%s", loadedString);
   } else {
      printf("Failed to open file for reading!\n");
   } 
   fclose(pFile);

   printf("Loaded string is %s", loadedString);

   return 0;
}
```

The main thing that changes if your terminal is operating in a wide-character mode is that the wide-character streams are likely contain a lot of individual nul bytes, which would be interpreted as string terminators in an ordinary C string.  That's the only reason why the approach above would not be expected to work in conjunction with such a terminal mode.

If your terminal is running in a wide-character mode, on the other hand, then your easiest way forward is probably to just change to wide strings and wide I/O universally, but there should be no reason to change locale or modify stream modes.

If you want to handle both wide and narrow terminal modes then you would want to *check*, not set, the locale to try to figure out which you're dealing with.  You would then use that to choose between narrow style and wide style operation.